# Cannot find forgerock openDJ 3.5.1 maven jars

Tags: openam, opendj

I am trying to use openDj 3.5.1 or 3.5.2 and have a maven dependency on it. However, i cannot find the jar at https://maven.forgerock.org/repo/webapp/#/home or https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.forgerock.opendj

Can someone help me getting this jar using maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently forgerock decided to release these jars into their private-release repo, and not in public repos. So, if you have forgerock's backstage account then you can get them using basic authentication through maven

Comment: This is nothing new, maintenance versions were not released to the public repositories before the business model change in 2017 April either.

Answer (score 3):

Please see this: [Is OpenDJ, OpenAM and OpenIAM free software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645330/is-opendj-openam-and-openiam-free-software/27949320#27949320).

If you are a ForgeRock customer, then you should contact support.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register at forgerock website.
Go to their download page and use the Search option.
Download the toolkit and the jars you require.
And install in your local repository.